# callablestatement to as400 not working

Tags: java, lotus-domino, ibm-midrange, db2-400

On a domino server I have an odbc connection to an as400 system. I can run a program on the as400 and send an input parameter by :

```
var sql:string ="CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('SBMJOB CMD(CALL PGM(DEMO/TESTDEMO) PARM(ABCDEF)) ',0000000048.00000)";
ps = con.prepareCall(sql);
ps.execute();
```

Nice , works, but now I would like to get some data back.
I thought I had to do this with a callablestatement, so I tried :

```
var con:Connection = null;
var cs:CallableStatement = null;
try {
  java.lang.Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  var con:java.sql.Connection=java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,pwd);
    sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error +"connection set /";
  var sql:string ="CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('CALL PGM(DEMO/TESTDEMO) (?,?))";
    sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error +"sql set /";
  cs = con.prepareCall (sql);
    sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error +"cs set /";
  cs.setString (1,'test');
    sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error +"input param set /";
  cs.registerOutParameter (2, Types.VARCHAR);
    sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error +"output param set /";
  cs.execute ();
    sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error +"executed /";
  var retour = cs.getInt (2);
    sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error +"output /"+retour;
  if (cs != null) {cs.close();sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error + "/ cs closed"}
  if (con != null) {con.close();sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error + "/ con closed"}
  }
catch (e){
  sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error+"Sql error ="+e.toString();
  if (cs != null) {cs.close();sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error + "/ cs closed"}
  if (con != null) {con.close();sessionScope.error = sessionScope.error + "/ con closed"}
  return;
}
```

When running this I get as error :

> connection set /sql set /cs set /Sql error
>   =java.lang.NullPointerException/ cs closed/ con closed

So the problem is about setting the input parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return values using QCMDEXC, but any program on IBM i can be turned into a stored procedure which can then return values either in a result set or a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ASSEMBLY_PARTS (IN  ASSEMBLY_NUM  DEC(7,0), 
                                 OUT NUM_PARTS     DEC(7,0), 
                                 OUT COST          DEC(9,2))
      LANGUAGE RPG
      PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL 
      FENCED
      EXTERNAL NAME ASSEMBLY
```

This defines a stored procedure for an RPG program named ASSEMBLY with one input parameter, and two output parameters. This is a modified example from the SQL reference found here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcrtpef.htm

You then call it similarly to the way you call the `QSYS.QCMDEXC` stored procedure. But the call looks more like `CALL ASSEMBLY_PARTS(ID, PARTS, COST)`. That is the closest I can get you right now since I don't have an instance of Domino to test with at the moment.

Comment: This procedure has to be made on IBM i ? How can I get data in and out in ssjs for the given example ?

Comment: @MarcJonkers The stored proc is to be defined in DB2 on the server. Hopefully, the server is one of the systems that replaced AS/400s many years ago. If it's old enough to be an actual "AS/400", you might need help creating the SP.

Comment: Seems like the name Nazis are present on StackOverflow. `IBM i` is the new name of the operating system that ran on the AS/400. It replaces and is equivalent to (with improvements) `OS/400`. `Power Systems` or `Pure Systems` is the new name of the hardware that used to be called `AS/400`. There are some in the community who quibble over naming. But, `OS/400` is to `Windows 2.0` as `IBM i v7.3` is to `Windows 10`. Yet we still just call it `Windows`. And many still call it `AS/400`. Note: `AS/400` was a package deal inexorably tied to `OS/400`. That is no longer the case.

Comment: It's a modern IBM i server (but I still call it an as400, sorry)
I can ask my collegue to make this kind of stored procedure on the IBM i server, but I still don't know how to interact with this stored procedure on the domino side in ssjs. Does anyone knows ?

Comment: Use the SQL `Call` statement.